# How to express core.autocrlf = false with .gitattributes?

Tags: git, gitattributes, core.autocrlf

This is amazing. With a gazillion posts on the Internet about `core.autocrlf` and `.gitattributes` I am still unable to figure out what to write in `.gitattributes` to express `core.autocrlf = false`

Can anyone clear the mist around it? I do not need all the fancy cases, just give me `core.autocrlf = false` in `.gitattributes`. Nothing more, but nothing less.

Comment: Thanks for using `.gitattributes`!  :D

Comment: There's actually several examples of this in https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you don't want line ending conversion on a file, set the `-text` attribute.  To turn off conversion on *all* files, set:

`* -text`

Note that this doesn't mean "this file isn't text" - that would be the `binary` attribute - it means "don't do text manipulations (line ending changes) on it".

Comment: This is __THE BEST__ thing you can do.... ever!!! Make it global, actually.

Comment: No.  Don't make it global.  `core.autocrlf` _is_ global, and that's the problem.  Different people can have different settings.  Line ending changes need to be per-repository (in `.gitattributes`), so that every contributor agrees.

Comment: Is there any special considerations if we also use Git LFS?

Comment: @mark No, git-lfs should work fine with this setup.  (Any files tracked by git-lfs will also set `-text` for good measure.)

Comment: @EdwardThomson but line-ending mangling is *bad*. Text editors support whatever line ending on whatever operating system, and that's been true for a *long time*.

Comment: @Mark I never said that line ending mangling was good.  Despite that, there are some tools that expect line endings in a particular format (make and cmd jump immediately to mind)

Comment: @Mark Try running a bash script that has CRLF. It's not "mangling" if it's fixing a problem.

Comment: @AlexDresko lots of shells work with arbitrary (or even inconsistent) line endings. If bash doesn't, I personally consider that a bug. Regardless, the whole point of this question/answer is to avoid setting it globally, and allow for old (or bad, or... cantankerous) tools that require specific line endings.